# MySQL CONCAT and INNER JOIN - Adding another child table

Tags: mysql, sql

The query below creates a hierarchical relationship with tables and records:

```
program -> accreditation_standard_group -> accreditation_standard -> learning_event
```

Base on the following tables structures:

```
+------------+----------------+
| program_pk |  program_name  |         
+------------+----------------+

+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+
| accreditation_standard_group_pk |  accreditation_standard_group | program_fk |            
+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+

+---------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------+
| accreditation_standard_pk | accreditation_standard | accreditation_standard_group_fk |          
+---------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------+

+-------------------+----------------------+---------------------------+
| learning_event_pk |  learning_event_name | accreditation_standard_fk |            
+-------------------+----------------------+---------------------------+
```

I now want to add another table as a sibling of table `learning_event` so that the relationship becomes:

```
program -> accreditation_standard_group -> accreditation_standard -> learning_event
                                                                  -> assessment
```

That is, tables `learning_event` and `assessment` have the parent `accreditation_standard`

```
+---------------+-------------+---------------------------+
| assessment_pk |  assessment | accreditation_standard_fk |            
+---------------+-------------+---------------------------+
```

Note that both table `learning_event` and table `assessment` have relationships to table `accreditation_standard` using the columns `accreditation_standard_fk` (which is not a true foreign_key...)

The original query, which works fine, See [**db-fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6PiURUaDwpdaXHmHCiJjsB/0), but does not contain table `assessment` as a sibling of table `learning_event` is:

```
SELECT CONCAT('program:', program_pk) AS global_id,
       program_name AS name,
       NULL AS parent_global_id
FROM program
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_pk) AS global_id,
       accreditation_standard_group AS name,
       CONCAT('program:', program_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM accreditation_standard_group 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', accreditation_standard) AS global_id,
       accreditation_standard AS name,
       CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM accreditation_standard
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', accreditation_standard, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
       learning_event_name AS name,
       CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', accreditation_standard) AS parent_global_id
FROM learning_event le
INNER JOIN accreditation_standard ass ON ass.accreditation_standard_pk = le.accreditation_standard_fk
INNER JOIN accreditation_standard_group asg ON ass.accreditation_standard_group_fk = asg.accreditation_standard_group_pk
```

How should I add the table assessment as required above?  Can this be added in the last `CONCAT` with an extra `INNER JOIN`?  Or does it need another `CONCAT` as well?

An example of the working code would be great.  See [**db-fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6PiURUaDwpdaXHmHCiJjsB/0)

NOTE:  I need to retain the format of the original query, just need to add the extra table as sibling as explained.

Comment: Thanks for providing a fiddle, that helps a lot! But please include the DDL and DML in your question itself too, so that the question remains understandable even if the fiddle is down.

Comment: table structures added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would another `UNION ALL` in the end provide what you want?

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('program:', program_pk) AS global_id,
       program_name AS name,
       NULL AS parent_global_id
FROM program
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_pk) AS global_id,
       accreditation_standard_group AS name,
       CONCAT('program:', program_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM accreditation_standard_group 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', accreditation_standard) AS global_id,
       accreditation_standard AS name,
       CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM accreditation_standard
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', accreditation_standard, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
       learning_event_name AS name,
       CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', accreditation_standard) AS parent_global_id
FROM learning_event le
INNER JOIN accreditation_standard ass ON ass.accreditation_standard_pk = le.accreditation_standard_fk
INNER JOIN accreditation_standard_group asg ON ass.accreditation_standard_group_fk = asg.accreditation_standard_group_pk
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', accreditation_standard, ',assessment:', assessment) AS global_id,
       assessment AS name,
       CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', accreditation_standard) AS parent_global_id
FROM assessment assess
INNER JOIN accreditation_standard ass ON ass.accreditation_standard_pk = assess.accreditation_standard_fk
INNER JOIN accreditation_standard_group asg ON ass.accreditation_standard_group_fk = asg.accreditation_standard_group_pk
```

Comment: also from my understanding the CONCAT in this context needs to be cumulative, i.e. build upon the previous CONCATs.  It will also need another INNER JOIN?

Comment: I've tried in the fiddle you shared and it looks to be the same format as the learning "brother/sister" table

Comment: Edited the answer and included the full SQL

Comment: Great job!  Thanks.  The only thing I would change is 'assessment le' to 'assessment asst' as 'le' is used by table learning_event.  It works either way though.  Thanks again!

Comment: great point. Updated to `assess`, `as`  is used for aliases